# Como hacer que el PictureBox inicie su animacion del centro hacia afuera?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, animación, picturebox

Bueno este es el codigo que tengo para darle fondo al PictureBox

```
case "C03":
                        imgC03.BackgroundImage = Prototype9.Properties.Resources.cbpot;
                        img = imgC03;
                        for (int w = 0; w < 1; w++)
                        {
                            timer1.Start();
                        }
                        break;
```

Con el codigo que pondre a continuacion es con el que se le da la animacion que quiero pero esta animacion inicia desde la esquina superior izquierda.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while(img.Width < 342)
            {
                img.Size = new Size(img.Width + 8, img.Height + 4);
                img.Refresh();
            }
                timer1.Stop();        
        }
```

Bien dicho esto ahora la idea es que este mismo recuadro del PictureBox en vez de iniciar la animacion desde la esquina superior izquierda, inicie la animacion desde el centro del mismo hacia afuera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumo que tu objeto `img` es un `PictureBox`, si es así, te propongo que hagas lo siguiente:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   while(img.Width < 342)
   {
      //Esta linea cambia la ubicación del objeto img, es decir el punto de la esquina superior izquierda
      img.Location = new Point(img.Location.X - 4, img.Location.Y - 2);
         //Esta cambia el tamaño del objeto img.
      img.Size = new Size(img.Width + 8, img.Height + 4);
      img.Refresh();
   }
   timer1.Stop();        
}
```

Lo que se debe hacer es cambiar el punto de la esquina superior izquierda en una cantidad numericamente igual a la mitad de lo que cambia el tamaño y con valor negativo, para que se reubique el control, en sentido inverso al que crece.

---

Ahora te agrego una observación sobre el primer procedimiento que incluyes en tu pregunta, ya que hay allí cosas con una logica muy cuestionable, me refiero al lo siguiente:

```
case "C03":
      imgC03.BackgroundImage = Prototype9.Properties.Resources.cbpot;
      img = imgC03;
      //Este lazo for solo acurrirá una ves cuando w toma valor cero
      for (int w = 0; w < 1; w++)
      {
        timer1.Start();
      }
      break;
```

Seria lo mismo haber escrito:

```
case "C03":
      imgC03.BackgroundImage = Prototype9.Properties.Resources.cbpot;
      img = imgC03;
      //El lazo for no haria falta para nada.
      timer1.Start();
      break;
```